# How to get data from SQL Server tables with document style DB structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database structure where I have three tables

- ObjectType
- ObjectProperty
- ObjectData

`ObjectType` stores entities like Customer, `ObjectProperty` stores entity properties like `Name`, `Age`, and `ObjectData` stores values for the properties like `Name Asif`, `Age 28`

I have created tables like this:

http://prntscr.com/ca344a

Data looks like this:

```
ObjectId    ObjectName
----------------------
1           Customer

PropertyId     PropertyName     ObjectId
----------------------------------------
    1             Id                  1
    2             Name                1

DataId  PropertyId    Date
--------------------------
   1        1         121
   2        2         Usama
   3        1         122
   4        2         waleed
```

But here problem is that how can I get Name and Age of one Entity (Customer) using SQL.

[EDIT]

SQL script to generate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectData]
(
    [DataId] [int] NULL,
    [PropertyId] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectProperty]
(
    [PropertyId] [int] NULL,
    [PropertyName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectType]
(
    [ObjectId] [int] NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Requirement is that user can add property any time to objectproperty table. So it is like dynamic entity model. (EDIT like this prntscr.com/ca3hou)

Desired output:

```
PropertyId  DataId   Date
----------------------------
1             1      121
2             2      Usama
```

Please note, a new property can be added anytime in objectproperty table.

Do I need to modify database structure ?

Please suggest

Thanks.

Comment: Read [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/) and then do as they say in this article - **RUN AS HELL!** This is a **horribly inefficient** design and will cause you countless hours of pain and suffering - **don't do this!**

Comment: Lets try this a third time: There is no way to tell that `Usama` is connected to `ObjectId=1`. So your design has an issue. Generally speaking EAV designs should be avoided unless you have a good understanding of the pros and cons.g

Answer (score 0):

Try This: Please consider table and column name exactly what you have

```
SELECT ot.ObjectName, op.PropertyName, od.data
FROM ObjectType ot
INNER JOIN OBJECTPROPERTY OP ON op.ObjectId = ot.ObjectId
INNER JOIN ObjectData OD ON od.PropertyId = op.PropertyId
```

About exact structure please share your full requirement then we can suggest.

Comment: @S Bohara, I jsut updated the question with requirement. I am not getting desired result with above query as you can see at http://prntscr.com/ca398h. I need to get one customer data.

Comment: Why should he *try this*? Can't you explain how doing thiswill solve the jser's problem in  a way that's cleer, instead of just saying *Try this* with no reason the poster should do so. Why should the poster *try this*? What speficif gain will then obtain by doing so?

Comment: The suggested queries last column is `data` but in your screenshot it is `PropertyId`. So firstly, use the actual posted query. Secondly, if it does not do what you're after then *explain* why. Don't just post a screenshot.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I mentioned that I need one entity data and posted screenshot to show that what i get with the query sent. My column name is Propertyid in database and screenshots

Comment: You need to show an explicit example of what output you are expecting by editing it into your original question. Don't post screenshots. Don't post it in the comments. Without a clear example of the output you are expecting, we are all guessing. The screenshot looks like only one entity to me, it just happens to be on four lines. The other thing to consider is that there is no way to tell in your data model whether ObjectID 1 has the name Usama or Waleed. So yes there is an issue with your data model. You probably need an `ObjectID` column in it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I just edited question with tables script and what is required.

Comment: Excellent, that makes it more likley to get an answer now. I see you have posted your required output in a picture in another comment. This is key information. It would be helpful if you edited your question and added this info also (as text)

Comment: and yes... you do need to change your database structure. There is no way to tell if objectid 1 has a name of Waleed or Usama. I have more info a prior comment

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script .

```
      WITH cte_date
       AS( SELECT d.DataId,d.PropertyId,d.[Date],ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PropertyID ORDER BY PropertyID) RNO
           FROM ObjectType o
             JOIN [ObjectProperty] p ON o.ObjectId=P.ObjectId
               And o.objectName='Customer' 
                And p.PropertyName in ('Name','Id')
             JOIN objectData d On p.Propertyid= d.propertyId)
    SELECT DataId,PropertyId,[Date]
    FROM cte_date
    WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: Its returns this http://prntscr.com/ca3hef where as i want this http://prntscr.com/ca3hou